# SQL Simple Inner Join

Tags: sql, inner-join

I'm Noob in SQL.

Ive 3 tables:

```
TB_ITEM
{
    TB_ITEM_ID int primary key,
    TB_ITEM_CAT_ID int,
    TB_ITEM_SUBCAT_ID int,
    TB_ITEM_NAME varchar(350)
    add constraint FK_ITEM_CAT foreign key(TB_ITEM_CAT_ID)
    references TB_ITEM_CAT(TB_ITEM_CAT_ID),
    add constraint FK_ITEM_SUBCAT foreign key(TB_ITEM_SUBCAT_ID)
    references TB_ITEM_SUBCAT(TB_ITEM_SUBCAT_ID)
}
TB_ITEM_CAT
{
    TB_ITEM_CAT_ID int primary key,
    TB_ITEM_CAT_NAME varchar(350)
}
TB_ITEM_SUBCAT
{
    TB_ITEM_SUBCAT_ID int primary key,
    TB_ITEM_CAT_ID int,
    TB_ITEM_SUBCAT_NAME
    add constraint FK_CAT foreign key(TB_ITEM_CAT_ID)
    references TB_ITEM_CAT(TB_ITEM_CAT_ID)
}
```

TABLE "TB_ITEM" HAS 416 RECORDS.

Ive tried,follow query:

```
select a.TB_ITEM_NAME, b.TB_ITEM_CAT_NAME, c.TB_ITEM_SUBCAT_NAME from 
TB_ITEM a inner join 
TB_ITEM_CAT b on a.TB_ITEM_CAT_ID = b.TB_ITEM_CAT_ID 
   inner join TB_ITEM_SUBCAT c 
on a.TB_ITEM_SUBCAT_ID = c.TB_ITEM_SUBCAT_ID
```

and result is:1162 results

I mean:I want to retrieve only those 416 records from TB_ITEM and its CATEGORIES NAMES and SUB-CATEGORIES NAME
from TB_ITEM_CAT and TB_ITEM_SUBCAT

Is this query wrong?Why 1162 records instead only 416?

Any ideias?

Comment: If there are multiple rows of `TB_ITEM` that have the same entry for `TB_ITEM_SUBCAT_ID`, then they'll match multiple times with the column of the same name in `TB_ITEM_SUBCAT_NAME`.  At a glance, that's probably the issue.

Comment: Try adding a `group by 1,2,3` at the end of your query.  The issue could be that you have duplicate rows.

Comment: with group by,result count is 1152. -10

Comment: As far as I know the query should work, the join fields are primary keys so shouldn't be duplicates. But doesn't work so I missing something...

Comment: Can an item belong in multiple categories?

Comment: yes there are multiple records with same entry for TB_ITEM_SUBCAT_ID

Comment: That's probably your culprit, then.  Try Rajeev's query below and see if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to ensure that TB_ITEM_SUBCAT is joined correctly to avoid duplicates

See if this works:

```
 select a.TB_ITEM_NAME, b.TB_ITEM_CAT_NAME, c.TB_ITEM_SUBCAT_NAME from 
 TB_ITEM a inner join 
 TB_ITEM_CAT b on a.TB_ITEM_CAT_ID = b.TB_ITEM_CAT_ID 
 inner join TB_ITEM_SUBCAT c 
 on a.TB_ITEM_SUBCAT_ID = c.TB_ITEM_SUBCAT_ID and a.TB_ITEM_CAT_ID = c.TB_ITEM_CAT_ID
```

Comment: WOW!Now that works!I mean,what was the problem?Can you explain?

Comment: I noticed that the TB_ITEM_SUBCAT table has a foreign key to the TB_ITEM_CAT table, which led me to the suspicion that TB_ITEM_SUBCAT_ID may not be the primary key for the table. The primary key is probably a combination of TB_ITEM_CAT_ID and TB_ITEM_SUBCAT_ID. So the join from TB_ITEM should check the equality to both the columns. You could probably verify this by looking at the data in TB_ITEM_SUBCAT table.

Answer (score 3):

Your `TB_ITEM` has two FKs

```
add constraint FK_ITEM_CAT foreign key(TB_ITEM_CAT_ID)
    references TB_ITEM_CAT(TB_ITEM_CAT_ID)

add constraint FK_ITEM_SUBCAT foreign key(TB_ITEM_SUBCAT_ID)
    references TB_ITEM_SUBCAT(TB_ITEM_SUBCAT_ID)
```

And your joins match

```
from 
TB_ITEM a inner join 
 inner join TB_ITEM_CAT b 
 on a.TB_ITEM_CAT_ID = b.TB_ITEM_CAT_ID 

inner join TB_ITEM_SUBCAT c 
on a.TB_ITEM_SUBCAT_ID = c.TB_ITEM_SUBCAT_ID
```

This means your query rowcount must be less than or equal to the table count.

So this leaves the following possiblities...

1. Your count of the table isn't correct
2. The joins in your query as posted don't match what you're trying
3. You've got something else in your join that we're not seeing
4. You're not referencing the object you think your are. (perhaps a view or a synonym)
5. Or your primary key or foreign key isn't what you say they are. e.g. your key is a composite key

Try adding schema names e.g `dbo.TB_ITEM` to your tables in the from clause and rechecking the others.

Comment: I'm glad you got your problem solved. I updated my answer to include the other possibility that you what you posted about the keys wasn't accurate (as Rajeev was able to figure out). I'm leaving this answer for the possibility that this may help someone in the future. Also as an aside you probably want to reference answers by the poster rather than "above" or "below" since the position may change.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that in the results it's creating a record for every time an item matches a category/subcategory. So for example, if item A has 3 categories it belongs to, the results would include 3 instances of item A, matching each of those categories. Naturally, this is compounded by the subcategories table, and joining that as well. If an item had 3 categories and 2 subcategories that would return 6 results!

If you don't care about which category and/or subcategory you select for a particular item you can just do something like this:

```
select a.TB_ITEM_NAME, b.TB_ITEM_CAT_NAME, c.TB_ITEM_SUBCAT_NAME from 
TB_ITEM a inner join 
TB_ITEM_CAT b on a.TB_ITEM_CAT_ID = b.TB_ITEM_CAT_ID 
   inner join TB_ITEM_SUBCAT c 
on a.TB_ITEM_SUBCAT_ID = c.TB_ITEM_SUBCAT_ID
GROUP BY a.TB_ITEM_ID
```

Also if you just want to get a single instance of each item and a comma separated list of the categories, sub categories, I THINK something like this should work:

```
select a.TB_ITEM_NAME, GROUP_CONCAT(b.TB_ITEM_CAT_NAME), GROUP_CONCAT(c.TB_ITEM_SUBCAT_NAME) from 
TB_ITEM a inner join 
TB_ITEM_CAT b on a.TB_ITEM_CAT_ID = b.TB_ITEM_CAT_ID 
   inner join TB_ITEM_SUBCAT c 
on a.TB_ITEM_SUBCAT_ID = c.TB_ITEM_SUBCAT_ID
GROUP BY a.TB_ITEM_ID
```

I hope this helps you understand!